# How to run multiple selenium/webdriverjs tests with different inputs in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm currently running selenium tests synchronously that takes in a different value for a sendkeys function from an array. I'm running it with a timeout of 35 seconds as the test takes about 25 seconds to complete. It's not usual for me to have 80+ inputs in the orders array.

I do have another test I run with a set amount of inputs (8) that I can just run using await in an async function so I'm wondering if there is a better way for me to run these tests back-to-back using promises and how I may be able to accomplish that. I've tried using map with promise.all, but that will try to run the tests all at once, but I want them to run one at a time.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
const { webdriver, Builder, By, Key, Until } = require("selenium-webdriver");
const promise = require("selenium-webdriver").promise;

const orders = ["order1", "order2", "order3","order4"];

runLoop = async () => {
  for (const order of orders) {
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 35000));
    test(order);
  }
};
runLoop();


async function test(order) {
  let driver;

  driver = await new Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();
  await driver.manage().window().maximize();

  try {
    await driver.get(
      "https://myWebsite.com"
    );

    await driver
      .findElement(
        By.xpath(
          '//*[@id="ctl00_BodyContent_OrderSearchForm1_txtSearchString"]'
        )
      )
      .sendKeys(`${order}`);
  } 

  // RUN TESTS WITH ORDER
  
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err);

  } 
  
  finally {
    await driver.quit();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out, you can use await in a for loop.

```
runLoop = async () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
    await test(orders[i]);
  }
};
runLoop();
```

Comment: I hade the same problem and unfortunately after the first run I get this error message: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchSessionError: This driver instance does not have a valid session ID (did you call WebDriver.quit()?) and may no longer be used.` and `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().` Any idea what can be the issue here?